# Can't calculate growth rate of function

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, discrete-mathematics, big-o

[image]

Hello, I am trying to solve a question in above image, but I can't.

Specially, my question is about C(n) in the image, I got "7logn + n^(1/3)" at the end.

we know that left side of + sign, "7logn<=n for all n>7 (witness c=1, k=7)", and right side of + sign, "n^(1/3)<=n".

Both sides between + sign from my perspective is O(n) and thus whole C(n) is O(n).

But why the answer is Big-theta(n^1/3)?

Comment: You did your math correctly, and you are quite right that C(n) is in O(n), but why do you think that means it's not Θ(∛n)? Θ(∛n) is a subset of O(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only true if log is the logarithm of base 2 (then log(8) = 3, because 2^3 = 8).

8^(log(n)/9) = (8^log(n))^(1/9) = (n^log(8))^(1/9) = (n^3)^(1/9) = n^(3 * 1/9) = n^(1/3)

n^(1/3) is the same as the 3rd root of n.

It is O(n^(1/3)) and not O(log(n)) because the former term is growing faster:

Limit of n towards infinity of log(n) / (n^(1/3)) equals 0. If you would have to switch the expressions to get 0 then the other one would be growing faster. E.g. n + log(n) would be O(n) because n is growing faster, not to be confused with n * log(n) which is O(n * log(n)).